# How to implement change tracking with IdentityDbContext in .NET MVC 5 (NOT core)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, change-tracking

I've implemented some basic change tracking with Entity Framework. The app uses .NET MVC, EF, Owin, ASP.NET Identity. In my `DbContext` class (which inherits from `IdentityDbContext`) I override the `SaveChanges` method (`public override int SaveChanges()`) and have hooked into the `ChangeTracker`. From there I populate a `ChangeLog` table. This all works flawlessly when modifying my own entities (adverts, in this case).

However... When making changes to the logged in user via the `UserManager` class (in `IdentityConfig.cs`) - these changes aren't recorded. Using the debugger - this is because `SaveChanges()` method is never hit. Why? What mechanism is `IdentityDbcontext` using to track and persist changes to the User? Most importantly, how do I have it make use of the change tracking I've written?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre]. How does your UserManager get its DbContext, do you pass yours or does an IdentityDbContext get instantiated?

Comment: So I just realised, which I'd already stumbled upon earlier without realising, that the UserManager hits SaveChangesAsync in the DbContext, not SaveChanges. Using the debugger confirms this.

My next question is - from within the `SaveChangesAsync` method, how do I get the logged in users Id? `HttpContext` isn't available (but it is within the regular `SaveChanges` method)

Comment: Never mind, solved that too, thanks for your help. Happy to post code if anyone's interested

Comment: @suraj how did you solved it?

Comment: @patsy2k Really sorry, I've only just seen this. I can post up the code tomorrow if you still need it?

Comment: @suraj can you provide your solution? I am having the same isssue and wanted to make an audit log entry for User changes.